# How can i get a symbol, produced by putting one character on the surface on the other, in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

I need to type [image] in my document, but I can't find the proper way to do it. It looks like it was made by combining `$\Diamond$` and `$\Box$` somehow. So how can i get it?

Comment: If you would make a [mre] that produces the symbols separately, I'm sure we can help you to combine them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't find the symbol available somewhere, I would think using tikz would be an easy solution. Small tikz pictures can be inlined or defined as a command. The symbol can be created as contents of overlapping nodes, the node shapes or a handmade tikz path. The following code shows some examples:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,math}

\newcommand{\myawesomesymbol}[1]{\tikz[baseline=-1mm]{\node[diamond, draw, inner sep=#1]{}; \node[draw, inner sep=#1]{};}}
\newcommand{\mythicksymbol}[1]{\tikz[baseline=-1mm]{\node[thick, diamond, draw, inner sep=#1]{}; \node[thick, draw, inner sep=#1]{};}}

\newcommand{\myhandmadesymbol}[1]{\tikz[baseline=-1mm]{ 
\draw[] (-#1,-#1) -- (#1,-#1) -- (#1,#1) -- (-#1,#1) -- (-#1,-#1); 
\draw[] (-2.1*#1, 0) -- (0,2.1*#1) -- (2.1*#1,0) -- (0, -2.1*#1)-- (-2.1*#1,0);}}

\begin{document}
This is some sentence with this symbol \tikz[baseline=-1mm]{\node[diamond, draw]{}; \node[draw]{};} in the text. 
This one \myawesomesymbol{.7mm} is smaller and as a command and there is a larger one: \myawesomesymbol{3mm}, or scaling with the font size: {\tiny tiny  \myawesomesymbol{.5ex}}, {\small small \myawesomesymbol{.5ex}}, Large {\Large \myawesomesymbol{.5ex}}. 
Maybe thick: \mythicksymbol{1.5mm}. 
Using tikz, it is also possible to overlay math symbols as suggested in the question: \tikz[baseline=-1mm]{\node[]{\Huge$\diamond$}; \node[]{\tiny$\Box$};}, however, the spacing is not perfect. 
And last, in case the little overlapping corners are a concern, it is still possible drawing it by hand: small \myhandmadesymbol{.1}, larger \myhandmadesymbol{.2}, scaling with font \myhandmadesymbol{.5ex}.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Nice solution! Maybe you could include one more example with something like `\myawesomesymbol{0.5ex}` so that it automatically scales with the surrounding font size?